# Como Inserir Multiplos itens usando o react-native-sqlite-storage

Tags: react, react-native, sqlite

Estava desenvolvendo um aplicativo usando o react-native-sqlite-storage mas me deparei com um problema muito estranho, hora meu código funciona e hora não, não dá pra entender, pra tentar investigar cheguei ao seguinte código:

```js
/* Conexão */
const db = SQLite.openDatabase(
  'candy.db',
  '1.0',
  'candy',
  20000,
  () => console.log('banco de dados aberto'),
  (error) => console.log('error', error),
);

/* Objeto estático para teste */
const order = {
  items: [{
      nome: "Snickers",
      quantidade: 1,
      preco: 3,
      codigo_de_barras: 123
    },
    {
      nome: "Bala de goma",
      quantidade: 1,
      preco: 1,
      codigo_de_barras: 1234
    },
  ],
  cliente: {
    id: 1
  },
  status: "NAO PROCESSADO"
};

/* Transação */
db.transaction(tx => {
  tx.executeSql(
    "INSERT INTO pedidos (id_usuario,status) VALUES (?,?)", [order.cliente.id, order.status],
    () => {},
    (e) => console.log(e)
  )

  /* Parte que ocorre o erro */
  order.items.forEach(produto => {
    db.executeSql(
      `INSERT INTO pedido_itens (id_pedido,codigo_de_barras,quantidade, preco) 
          VALUES((SELECT last_insert_rowid()+1 from pedidos), ?,?,?)`, [produto.codigo_de_barras, produto.quantidade, produto.preco],
      () => console.log(produto, "inserido com sucesso no banco de dados"),
      (e) => console.log(e)
    )
  })
})
```

O estranho é que eu tenho dois itens em order.itens ambos os itens são exibidos no console mas nem sempre são inseridos na banco de dados, essa parte não faz sentido pra mim pois então passando pela mesma função juntos. Se ainda fosse o caso de serão inseridos como tempos diferentes faria sentido pra mim pois essa biblioteca oferece suporte para promises que não estou usando no momento, mas até esse comportamento estranho eu estava conseguindo desenvolver normal.
alguém pode me dar um direção do que fazer?? já não tenho mais ideias.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sugiro que utilize uma função assíncrona para isso. Mesmo que de fora não faça sentido, mas essa questão de chamadas se atropelarem é real.

```
class DataAccess {
    executeSql = async(sql, params) => {
            const tx = await this.transaction();
            tx.executeSql(sql, params, () => Promise.resolve(), error => {
                throw error;
            });
        }
 /* outras implementações */
}
const da = new DataAccess();
```

Depois faça o loop dos items chamando a assíncrona função que criamos.

```
async function insert() {
    // promise all não garante a ordem execução 
    // entao usamos o await (async)
    await Promise.all(order.items.map(async produto => {
        try {
            await da.executeSql(`INSERT INTO pedido_itens (id_pedido,codigo_de_barras,quantidade, preco) 
      VALUES((SELECT last_insert_rowid()+1 from pedidos), ?,?,?)`, [produto.codigo_de_barras, produto.quantidade, produto.preco]);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    }));
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Descobri o problema era nesse SQL :` INSERT INTO pedido_itens (id_pedido,codigo_de_barras,quantidade, preco)  VALUES((SELECT last_insert_rowid()+1 from pedidos)`, alterei para : `INSERT INTO pedido_itens (id_pedido,codigo_de_barras,quantidade,preco) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM pedidos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1),?,?,?)` e tudo funcionou, vou escolher a sua pergunta e assim que liberar o tempo do bounty eu te bonifico, valeu demais não fosse sua resposta nem sei se ia voltar a mexer nesse projeto.